# Advanced grifting techniques

Tags: dialogue, realism, community

*Community* season 6 episode 9: *Grifting 101*

Jeff Winger says:

> How was grifting class? Did you teach some advanced techniques; only you could understand? *The Brown Betty*, *The Texas Well Baby*, *The Reverse Jim Gaffigan*?

[image]

Are these references to real grifts/cons/scams?

What do they entail?

Comment: Quite doubtful they're real. (Although, the 2nd one could be a reference to [Baby Jessica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_McClure) and hoaxes like the [Balloon Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balloon_boy_hoax))

Answer (score 3):

My instinct is that the ["**Brown Betty**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_Betty_(dessert)) is some kind of [Food Contamination Hoax](http://hoaxes.org/archive/display/category/food_contamination); where you place something unpalatable inside something you've bought in the hopes of getting compensation from the vendor. There have been some notable [non-scam instances](http://home.bt.com/news/odd-news/maggots-mice-and-deadly-spiders-21-of-the-most-disgusting-things-found-in-food-11363954811297) of this happening.

The "**Texas Well Baby**" would presumably be based on [pretending someone is stuck down a well](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/We're_Sending_Our_Love_Down_the_Well) (the modern variation is that someone is [stuck overseas](http://abcnews.go.com/Technology/stranded-traveler-scam-hacks-victims-emails-asks-contacts/story?id=16774896)) in order to solicit donations from concerned parties. There are, of course [real instances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_McClure) of this occurring.

Answer (score 1):

Texas Well Baby may be an attempt to gain charitable donations from a personal tragedy, much as [Jessica McClure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_of_Jessica_McClure#In_popular_culture) did after falling down a Texas well as a young child.

According to the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Reverse%20Jim%20Gaffigan), the Reverse Jim Gaffigan is the sale of individually wrapped Hot Pockets as a street vendor. Hot pockets are not normally packaged for individual sale.

Brown Betty is a type of cobbler dessert with fruit and sweetened crumbs. It also has a number of [progressively more disgusting definitions](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Brown%20Betty) in the Urban Dictionary. How any of these are connected to a grift or scam, I do not know, though mixing definitions could support User7812's theory that it is a food contamination hoax.

Comment: The Urban Dictionary entry was clearly written in response to Community episode.

Comment: The entry cites the Community line as an example of the term being used in a sentence. All Urban Dictionary entries show the word used in a sentence, with examples taken from pop culture whenever possible. That does not mean the definition given in the entry is not the actual definition of the term in popular use.

Comment: The purpose of providing a cite is to provide evidence, and a cite that is later than the episode has little evidentiary value. If it predated the episode, that would demonstrate that the show was referring to a pre-existing term. With the entry being later, all we have is someone on the internet claiming this is what it means, and likely inspired by the show to make up a definition.

Comment: So if Shakespeare uses a term, I need to find a dictionary published before 1590 in order to find a valid definition? With all due respect, that's nonsense.

Comment: If you want to address the question of whether Shakespeare was referring to a pre-existing definition versus coining a new meaning, then yes, you need a source prior to Shakespeare. I don't see what's so hard to understand about this.

Comment: But the show did not define the term -- that's the whole point of the question. The Urban Dictionary definition I cite was not on the show. Are you suggesting that someone invented a definition for the term and entered into the UD site because they heard the term on a TV show?